# How do I make a command more generalized?

Tags: macros

So the command is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}}
```

How can I make it so that beta can be replaced with anything. So I can type `\yhat` and then get `\hat{y}` or whatever else I might want to put a hat over. I just feel like doing that is quicker and more efficient. Is this possible without having tons of different commands for every possible scenario?

The editor I am using is TexMaker if that matters.

Comment: Does it really pay off to save two keystrokes?  I usually use keyboard shortcuts for all of this.  In Emacs I simply type `\`^ \`b` to get `\hat{\beta}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I think it helps. I am also more used to this. Another example of this would be:

\newcommand{\betahati}{\hat{\beta}_{i}}

This saves even more key strokes.

How did you set up that keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I'm using Emacs with the AucTeX extension.  When you turn on LaTeX math mode using `C-c ~` you can use the shortcuts described above.

Comment: When I also turn on `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`, I can easily type your required sequence using `\`^\`b→_i` ([screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bF69.gif)).

Comment: @HenriMenke that's interesting. Would you recommend emacs for someone like me who is just starting to learn LaTex?

Comment: That is something you have to find out for yourself.  Keep in mind that in Emacs all the shortcuts will be different from what you are used to (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+Z do very different things in Emacs).  I would say it has a steep learning curve but once you know how things work you can be very productive with it, especially because it is programmable so you can define arbitrarily complex keybindings.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX based solution.

Suppose the input is of the form `\<x>hat`. The solution relies on the following working assumptions about `<x>`:

- If `<x>` consists of a *single* alphabetic character, e.g., `\ahat` or `\zhat`, then the input is transformed to `\hat{<x>}`, e.g., `\hat{a}` or `\hat{z}`.
- If `<x>` consists of *two or more* alphabetic characters, e.g., `\alphahat` or `\Omegahat`, then the input is transformed to `\hat{\<x>}`, e.g., `\hat{\alpha}` or `\hat{\Omega}`. Put differently, it is assumed that `<x>` is really a macro that's missing the backslash prefix.

  An immediate consequence of this working assumption is that, say, `\xyhat` will *not* be transformed to `\hat{xy}`. Instead, it will be transformed to `\hat{\xy}` -- likely causing a crash unless `\xy` happens to be defined as a valid macro. I trust this isn't much of a restriction, as it doesn't make much sense to begin with to think about placing a narrow `^` accent symbol above `xy` -- or any other multi-letter combination, really.
- If `<x>` is either empty or does not consist exclusively of alphabetic characters, nothing is done. Thus, `\hat{a}` and `\hat{\alpha}` are not modified. And if your LaTeX file happens to contain `\,hat`, say, it won't be modified either: TeX will simply output a thinspace (`\,`) followed by the letters `h`, `a`, and `t`.

The solution consists of a Lua function (called `myhat`) which does all of the work. This function is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, giving it a preprocessor role: The function's work is done at a very early stage, *before* TeX does any of its usual processing. Thus, TeX never gets to "see" `\ahat` and `\alphahat`; it will only ever see `\hat{a}` and `\hat{\alpha}`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function myhat ( s ) -- this function does all of the work
   s = s:gsub ( "\\(%a)hat"   , "\\hat{%1}" )
   s = s:gsub ( "\\(%a%a-)hat", "\\hat{\\%1}" )
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}   
% Assign 'myhat' to the 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", myhat, "myhat")}
   
\begin{document}
$\alphahat, \betahat, \dots, \psihat, \omegahat$;
$\Gammahat, \Deltahat, \dots, \Psihat, \Omegahat$; 
$\ahat, \bhat, \dots, \zhat$;
$\Ahat, \Bhat, \dots, \Zhat$.

% Verify that output is the same if standard syntax is used:
$\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}, \dots, \hat{\psi}, \hat{\omega}$;
$\hat{\Gamma}, \hat{\Delta}, \dots, \hat{\Psi}, \hat{\Omega}$; 
$\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \dots, \hat{z}$;
$\hat{A}, \hat{B}, \dots, \hat{Z}$.
\end{document}
```